# QueryDsl doesn't generate the correct type

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

QueryDsl don't generate the correct type in QClass. It generate me a NumberPath instead of EnumPath. Why ?

BaseEnum interface :

```
 public interface BaseEnum {

    int getOrdinal();

}
```

BooleanEnum enum:

```
import com.kryptonic.KRPC.core.BaseEnum;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;


@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum BooleanEnum implements BaseEnum {
        IS_FALSE(false, "Non"),
        IS_TRUE(true,"Oui");

        @Setter
        private boolean is;

        @Setter
        private String nameFr;

        @Override
        @JsonValue
        public int getOrdinal() {
            return this.ordinal();
        }

}
```

Entity :

```
   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "int(11) default 1 comment 'Activer ou non la vente sur la marché'")
    private BooleanEnum Sell = BooleanEnum.IS_TRUE;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "int(11) default 1 comment 'Activer ou non achat sur le marché'")
    private BooleanEnum Buy = BooleanEnum.IS_TRUE;
```

QueryDsl generate :

```
public final NumberPath<BooleanEnum> Buy = createNumber("Buy", BooleanEnum.class);

public final NumberPath<BooleanEnum> Sell = createNumber("Sell", BooleanEnum.class);
```

- QueryDsl generate NumberPath instead of EnumPath.

Error :

```
Error:(34, 29) java: type argument com.kryptonic.KRPC.entity.BooleanEnum is not within bounds of type-variable T

Error:(34, 60) java: method createNumber in class com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.BeanPath<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<? super A>
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<com.kryptonic.KRPC.entity.BooleanEnum>
  reason: inference variable A has incompatible upper bounds com.kryptonic.KRPC.entity.BooleanEnum,java.lang.Number,java.lang.Comparable<?>

Error:(36, 29) java: type argument com.kryptonic.KRPC.entity.BooleanEnum is not within bounds of type-variable T

Error:(36, 61) java: method createNumber in class com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.BeanPath<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<? super A>
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<com.kryptonic.KRPC.entity.BooleanEnum>
  reason: inference variable A has incompatible upper bounds com.kryptonic.KRPC.entity.BooleanEnum,java.lang.Number,java.lang.Comparable<?>
```

Comment: This seems like a bug. You can report it at https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues

Perhaps it was intentional that an enum mapped by ordinal maps to a number path, but compilation should definitely succeed either way and it seems it does not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.